# AngularJs, accessing dynamic value in model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can i access the dynamic value generated of "name" property in model. Following is the code:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="que in backgroundInfo.questions">
    <tr>
        <td>{{que.id}} {{que.text}}</td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="{{que.id}}" value="Yes"  ng-model="backgroundInfo.questions.answer"/>Yes
            <input type="radio" name="queid" value="No"  ng-model="backgroundInfo.questions.answer"/>No
            <textarea name="comment{{que.id}}" ng-model="backgroundInfo.questions.comment[que.id]" rows="2"
                      cols="45"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: your question isn't very clear, but wouldn't you want to be bound to `que.answer` instead of `backgroundInfo.questions.answer`? in the former, you would have an answer for each `que`, in the latter, you would only have one answer for the entire group.

Answer (score 0):

You are so close

```
name="{{comment[que.id]}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this already solved? Because I think if want to have a name like ***name="comment[1]"***, the code should be like:

```
    <textarea name="comment[{{que.id}}]" ...
```

you can remove the ng-model cause I think, it will now work.
Furthermore, you can access the value of your textarea using

```
    angular.element(<name>)
```

in your controller.